# WooCommerce Bookings: how to set minimal date of date picker?

Tags: woocommerce, datepicker, woocommerce-bookings, mindate

In my business, I can only serve bookings with a lead time of 5 days. I am using WooCommerce Bookings but I do not know how to code the following.

When a customer is in the single product page and selects a date from the calendar element (‘date picker’) the earliest available date (‘mindate’) should always be ‘today + 5 days’.

I would be thankful for any support. I am quite a novice with that technology. Perhaps there is a hook or filter that can be used?

Thank you very much!

Comment: In the [WooCommerce Bookings dev docs > actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/bookings-action-and-filter-reference/#section-2), theres is only `wc_bookings_calendar_default_to_current_date` filter hook, that allows on the calendar to have "today" (true) or "first available booking date" (false).